# Magento 1 wrong Shipping rates

Tags: php, magento-1.9

we are using Webshopapps Product Matrix Rates pro version
after asking the developers of this extension they are saying that it's NOT the extension that is causing the issues as the logs say it's returning the correct values.

We have a shipping matrix setup for UK postcodes that requires a delivery charge for certain UK postcodes this is on a multi site setup which as 2 sites.

What should happen is per pallet added to the cart it should add £4.80 where a charge is required based on the postcode entered, so If I have 2 pallets the shipping cost to the postcode would be £9.60 and £4.80 for each extra pallet added there after, for the economical 2-3 day delivery.

On site one if I add 5 pallets the shipping cost is coming back at £28.80 where it should be £24

On site two If I add 5 Items the shipping cost is coming back at £9.60

I have no Idea why it is doing this as both sites are using the same code / theme apart from the logo and CSS for the colours of the site.

If anyone has any suggestions for a fix it would be much appreciated.

sorry I can't put code here or setting as I have no idea what I need to post for you to view.

Regards

Mal

Comment: Posting the Shipping CSV would be a start.

Comment: daft question, but how do i attach the CSV file?

Comment: If it's not too big, you can just paste it into the question.

Comment: Sorted, turns out after the developers going through the logs and a lengthy chat, which the boss remembered something very important they had done on the products on the other site I was trying to match, once I found this out it all made sense and got it working correctly, so there wasn't any bugs and it's working correctly all along ARGH!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted, turns out after the developers going through the logs and a lengthy chat, which the boss remembered something very important they had done on the products on the other site I was trying to match, once I found this out it all made sense and got it working correctly, so there wasn't any bugs and it's working correctly all along ARGH!!!!

Basically any products on the first site where the weight was over 850KG was set to 850KG regardless.

on the new site the correct weights have been added, so anything over 850KG was adding the extra cost, then they didn't update the CSV to reflect this.